# IDENTITY COLUMN ON and OFF is not Working with C#.net using Entity Spaces

Tags: asp.net, identity

I want to insert the value for a Identity Column explicitly in some cases and in some cases it has to be auto-incremented.I'm using this code in C#.net.But i'm not getting the Identity Column on and off.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
con.Open();
SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT InspectionSessionRecordingLibHeader ON", con);
ins.ExecuteNonQuery();

BLL.Inspector.InspectorManagement.InsertLibrary(inspectionid, libraryid, librarytitle, libCategory, LibDescription, iscentrallib);
SqlCommand ins1 = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT InspectionSessionRecordingLibHeader OFF", con);
ins.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: You are creating a SqlCommand named "ins1" but then you execute "ins". I assume you have the permissions on the table. Are there any errors when you execute?

Answer (score 0):

I miss-read that you are making the actual insert with Entity and only making SET IDENTITY_INSERT through a SqlCommand.

I think you're having problems because the entity model for the object in question has StoreGeneratedPattern=Identity for a column. You should look into that, but I would leave it as it is and try to change my solution so you wouldn't need to force insert into Identity columns.

**Original answer below:**
This is working for my test case:

```
protected void ChangeIdentityInsert()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ServerName\\SQLinstance;Initial Catalog=DEV;Integrated Security=SSPI");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblTest ON; INSERT INTO tblTest (IDrec, Somefield) VALUES (5, 'value 5'); SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblTest OFF;", conn);

    conn.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();

}
```

Create table for test:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTest](
[IDrec] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SomeField] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[IDrec] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```